# not able to send Headers Authorization from browser as well as rest client

Tags: php, rest, http-headers, authorization

While trying to send Header named Authorization, this is the response.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers → origin, x-requested-with, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods → PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Connection → close
Content-Type → application/json
Date → Sun, 06 Mar 2016 03:48:17 GMT
Server → Apache/2.4.12
Transfer-Encoding → chunked
X-Powered-By → PHP/5.5.31
```

I am sending like this:

```
var temp = "oldpassword=" + $scope.oldpassword + "&newpassword=" +     $scope.newpassword;
  //alert (temp);

  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://<url>/api/v1/change_password2',
    data: temp,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': api_key}

  }).then(
  // do whatever you want to do
  )
```

Can anyone help me why this is not working as same is working perfectly in localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Check your PHP version and PHP handler, i have faced the same issue when i was upgraded PHP version to 5.5.31, and PHP handler to CGI.

Then changing CGI to suPHP works for me.

Hope this will help you.